# Invalid HTML on revision history page

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list

The revision list contains the following HTML:

```
<td class="revcell1 vm" onclick="StackExchange.revisions.toggle('48d0b921-1b5f-4535-b4ec-b84eb1336890') ">
   <span id="rev-arrow-48d0b921-1b5f-4535-b4ec-b84eb1336890" class="expander-arrow-show" title="show/hide this revision's text" />
</td>
```

Given the HTML5 doctype, [this is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2816833/560648). *[Spans shall not be self-closed](http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/).*

The syntax highlighting in Firefox v19.0.2's "view source" window led me to this discovery.

---

[image: Screenshot of affected area]
[image: screenshot of Firefox v19.0.2 discovering the problem]

Comment: Is there any browser that actually has a problem with this?

Comment: @balpha: _The browser of my mind_.

Comment: Let me check whether that's on our supported list...

Comment: @balpha: I don't think that standards compliance is too much to ask for on a site for 1.8 million software developers, especially if it just means replacing a `/>` with a `></span>`. Or does Stack Overflow follow the MSIE model of software development?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I bet it might take unraveling 10 layers of indirection to fix, though :D

Comment: @balpha: Thank you! Balance has now been restored.